# .htaccess with pagination in php?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I am currently coding a pagination script into many parts of my site, this has been a well needed and requested feature and I have finally been able to come round and start coding it, it is all going well, until I find that my rewritten urls don't like working with the pagination urls.

So, an example page on my site would be news.php. This file structure can be something like news.php?id=5. I have rewritten the url like so:

/news/5/

```
## Rewrite URL's for News & Dev ##
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/$ /news.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)$ /news.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^news$ /news.php [L]
RewriteRule ^news/$ /news.php [L]
```

The pagination script I am using prepends two new variables in the url, the new url turns out to be this:

```
news.php?page=1&ipp=55id=5
```

I would really appreciate it if anyone could assist me in making the urls look better, as it defeats the object of having it in the first place if after they use the pagination, it changes the url back to a clunky and ugly url.

I don't want it to be required to have parts of the url, that is something I really don't want..

e.g I don't want the url to be required to be /news/1/55/5, instead id like it to be optional.

Thank you for your time, it is appreciated!

**Additional Information**

The links in my news script currently display like so:

```
 news.php?page=1&ipp=55id=5
```

I don't like to see ugly urls like that, and want to make the url look better using mod_rewrite, It would be better if the urls would display like so:

```
/news/PAGE/IPP/ID/ -> return news.php?page=1&ipp=55id=5
```

Also, to make it as user friendly as possible, I don't want any of the fields to be required as such, so for example I would like to have the following link accessible at all times without it requiring the other fields.

```
/news/ID/
```

Then, when the user clicks a pagination link, it would use the following link structure:

```
/news/PAGE/IPP/ID/ -> return news.php?page=1&ipp=55id=5
```

This is all from user feedback of my site, and is something that people have been asking for. Problem is, I don't understand even simple .htaccess

Thanks

Comment: I do not understand your question/the problem. Substantiate it with some example.

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey I have just added a more in depth information below original. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteBase /

# add slash to end of url if not present (and do a redirect)
RewriteCond $0 !/$
RewriteRule ^news([^\.]*)$ $0/ [L,R=302]

# rewrite url with format /news/[<id>/[<page>/[<ipp>/]]]
RewriteRule ^news/(?:([0-9]+)/)?(?:([0-9]+)/)?(?:([0-9]+)/)?$ /news.php?id=$1&page=$2&ipp=$3 [L]
```

Not sure what ipp is supposed to be, but my guess is it shows the number of item per page. I would personally not like to have that in my url.

Comment: Hello, IPP is Items per page, yes! Problem with this is it is simply causing a problem again with 404, for some reason this redirects to a url similar to /home/server/public_html/news/ . As previously stated, I lack knowledge with htaccess and know very little, so have no idea what has gone wrong! Thanks for the reply however :)

Comment: `again with 404`? You didn't mention that in your question. But it seem to be a problem of missing a RewriteBase. See updated code above.

Comment: Hello there, Thank you for your help, it finally seems to be getting somewhere! The 404 error is now gone, that is absolutely brilliant however the rewrite doesn't seem to be working, for example: news/1/1/1/ will redirect to /news.php/?id=1&page=1&ipp=1, is it possible to not have the ugly url there still? :) thank!

Comment: Sorry, it seems my local test environment was a bit different, but I was able to recreate your problem when I turned off MultiViews. I edited my answer to fix the problem.

Comment: That is working perfectly, many thanks for this I really appreciate it! I am sorry to bother you, however there is just one final thing. Is it possible with .htaccess to only have /news/1/ be required, and then the others not be required?

Comment: To make the first digit not optional, use `RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/(?:([0-9]+)/)?(?:([0-9]+)/)?$ /news.php?id=$1&page=$2&ipp=$3 [L]` instead

Answer (score 1):

You can have : 
`news/id/page/ipp` with

```
RewriteRule ^news(/?)$ news.php [L]
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)-(.*)_([0-9]+)(/?)$ news.php?page=$1&ipp=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

`news/1222-subjet-for-example_34`

return :
`news.php?page=1222&ipp=subject-for-example&id=34`

use (/?) instead of create many rules ;)

Hope it's works for you.

Comment: Hello there, firstly many thanks for your reply! The problem I am having with this is firstly:

I do not really understand htaccess, I have always found it confusing. 

Secondly, this seems to work when navigating to /news/ however adding any other fields on the end will result in a 404 error.